# canvas.drawBitmap() crashing on device

Tags: android, game-engine

I am new to android game development. Everything works fine on emulators and one of my android device but crashing in my nexus 4...

I am trying to obtain the user's touch using

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(!jump){
    first=true;
    makeajump();
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This is where the error occours in debug mode testing on nexus:

```
jcanvas.drawBitmap(mytree, xtree1,height-t1.getHeight(), null);//inside makeajump() line 404
```

it all works until user taps on the screen...

```
jcanvas = canvas;//set in onDraw(),jcanvas is global
```

here is my logcat when error occours:

```
06-18 18:40:55.752: E/InputEventReceiver(8523): Exception dispatching input event.
06-18 18:40:55.752: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:105)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at lion.run.vjapps.game.animal.GameView.makeajump(GameView.java:404)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at lion.run.vjapps.game.animal.GameView.dispatchTouchEvent(GameView.java:455)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8523):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 18:40:55.762: D/AndroidRuntime(8523): Shutting down VM
06-18 18:40:55.762: W/dalvikvm(8523): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a8d930)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:105)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at lion.run.vjapps.game.animal.GameView.makeajump(GameView.java:404)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at lion.run.vjapps.game.animal.GameView.dispatchTouchEvent(GameView.java:455)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 18:40:55.762: E/AndroidRuntime(8523):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help is appreciated...thanks a lot..

Comment: where to you draw inside onDraw()? jcanvas.drawBitmap(mytree, xtree1,height-t1.getHeight(), null);

Comment: no,
jcanvas.drawBitmap(mytree, xtree1,height-t1.getHeight(), null); is outside onDraw()..ie makeajump() method is outside onDraw()

Comment: you have to draw it in onDraw() using the canvas object. you can call invalidate to refresh the draw

Comment: i have assigned jcanvas = canvas; inside onDraw..jcanvas is global..
let me see,I will try it...

Comment: hey it works now...
I changed all drawBitmap to inside onDraw and everything works on the phone...thanks
I wonder why it worked on emulator and not on nexus without the change...

Comment: i will post this as an answer so that you can accept the same sice it solves your problem

Comment: it is always better to test it on a real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your draw code inside onDraw()

```
       canvas.drawBitmap(mytree, xtree1,height-t1.getHeight(), null);
```

You can do your computation outside onDraw() and call `invalidate()` to refresh the draw

```
public void invalidate ()
```

Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().